# cackphp multiple pagination with same page Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.4

My system has users with different role. I want show all users in same page in separate tables. So i did following things.

User Model (User.php)

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class User extends AppModel {

    public $useTable = 'users';

}
```

AUser model (Auser.php)

```
App::uses('User', 'Model');

class Auser extends User {

}
```

BUser model (Buser.php)

```
App::uses('User', 'Model');

class Buser extends User {

}
```

UsersController.php

```
App::uses('Auser', 'Model');
App::uses('Buser', 'Model');

class UsersController extends AppController {

    public function index() {
        $Auser = new Auser();
        $Buser = new Buser();

        $this->paginate = array(
            'Auser' => array(
                'conditions' => array('Auser.role' => 0),
                'limit' => 5
            ), 
            'Buser' => array(
                'conditions' => array('Buser.role' => 1),
                'limit' => 5
            ),           
        );

        $this->set('ausers', $this->paginate('Auser'));
        $this->set('busers', $this->paginate('Buser'));


 }
}
```

But it show following error.

Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.

What is the issue?

Comment: `$this->loadModel('Auser');` and not `$Auser = new Auser();`

Comment: Enable debug mode to get the real error.

Comment: Also, you cannot paginate twice..

Comment: See the stack trace and find in which line you get the errror. Just change your debug mode to get the erro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

error comma and  how to load models is so

```
$this->loadModel('Auser');
```

so:

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

    public function index() {
        $this->loadModel('Auser');
        $this->loadModel('Buser');
        $this->paginate = array(
            'Auser' => array(
                'conditions' => array('Auser.role' => 0),
                'limit' => 5
            ), 
            'Buser' => array(
                'conditions' => array('Buser.role' => 1),
                'limit' => 5
            )
        );

        $this->set('ausers', $this->paginate('Auser'));
        $this->set('busers', $this->paginate('Buser'));


 }
}
```